# Why won't my Gmail signature show up in replies to new senders?

Tags: gmail

I set up a Gmail signature under settings, and it pops up automatically when I compose a new email.

However, if someone emails me and I respond to them, it isn't automatically added to my response, which I find very inconvenient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22):

Have you had a look at the `Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it` option just below the signature edit box in your settings?

It’s probably that Gmail is adding your signature ***after*** the quoted text when you click reply.

Also, Gmail automatically trims content when you view emails:

> The "trimmed content" is typically quoted text from a previous message (identical content) and so they hide it so what's initially visible is only the NEW content.  Most people don't need to see the message they just sent that the person is replying to.  They just want to see the actual reply (new content).

From Google:

> Signatures are separated from the rest of your message by two dashes. To see a signature in Gmail, click the Show trimmed content button at the bottom of the message.

Comment: I have that option checked and no matter what the signature always ends up being part of the quote..

Comment: Update: I had to delete the signature and re-create it for it to work properly.

Comment: To confirm this, check an email that is sent; it will show up there.  In my opinion, this is a flaw in the user interface because it confuses users.  It would be better to have a little symbol (such as the `...` google uses to hide content) that is just to show that the signature is included, and click on it to customize/view the signature for any given email.

Answer (score 4):

Check on the check box that says "Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it". Once you check the box it will definitely resolve the issue for you. The only con I noticed was that after checking the box and then sending an email to verify it showed my signature, my signature would display right underneath the email I sent. Very close to the body of the email. So to resolve this issue I went back to gmail/settings/signature and right before my signature I pressed "enter" twice and saved changes. Now my signature not only displays correctly but it's also at a good spacing distance from the body of the email. Hope this helps.